# Send InLine message to channel with bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to Send `InlineMessage` to **Channel** with Bot **Automatically** ?

in `InlineMessage` after trying **user** to use Inline method Telegram sends `InlineQueryUpdate`, after that Bot should `AnswerInlineQuery` with `InlineQueryResults`. and then, User after select any of `InlineQueryResults` , Result is Send to user.

In **channel** because no body there to select any of Results, `InlineKeyboardSwitchInlineQueryButton` is **removed** from Markup.

So, What we can do?

---

**EDIT:**
Additional Information:
There is one **Bot** and One **Channel**. Bot is Admin of Channel.
Bot has **inLine Mode** and **inLine Reply Keyboard**

**Problem**:
When Bot sends Message (without any human user) with **inLine Reply Keyboard** to **Channel**, **inLine Reply Buttons** are **Removes** from Keyboard.
**But** when I send message (with human user) to channel **via** `inLine Mode` of Bot, every thing is OK.

**What I Need?**
I Need Send Message to `Channel` **via** `Bot` **without any human user**. or Best solution for this.

Comment: is my question un-underestandable?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand what do you want to do.

Comment: @MarcoBuster send Inline Message to Channel with bot , without any Human user!

Comment: An inline message like a GIF "via @gif" or a youtube video "via @youtube" with a Telegram bot?

Comment: I have bot , it Uses Both Inline and Normal Type. I Need to send Message to channel like Inline Type that's Show Over the Message **via** anyBot.

Comment: Because in `Normal Way`, when bot, send message in `channel`, Inline Buttons of Message is **Removed** from Reply Markup. @MarcoBuster

Comment: You want to send a message in a channel with an inline keyboard?

Comment: @MarcoBuster i insert information into Question

Comment: Are you the owner of the channel?

Comment: Yes, @CharlesOkwuagwu

Comment: wait, do you mean Group or Channel?

Comment: I Need Send Message to Channel via Bot @CharlesOkwuagwu

Comment: @PurTahan I feel you are getting it wrong... A channel is different from a group.

Comment: `bounty` did not help either 

Answer (score -1):

First of all, what language and library are you using? The method for doing this will differ vastly.

If it's Discord.JS, you need to get the channel object from somewhere. Either get a message's channel 'message.channel', find one from a server 'server.channels.find("name", "servernamehere")' or a ton of other different ways.

Comment: It's not different, Telegram Bot Api is `Rest Full`.
But For Answering You: [Telegram.Bot](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot) in `Asp.Net`